# Artifactory: Package management strategy to support n-2 releases

Tags: artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and trying to figure out the best strategy for my company's need. We've been using in-house package management system so far and want to go with more of industry standard solution.

Our situation:

1. We have on-prem deployed software. Since each customer has their own story and strategy for software update, we need to support more than the latest release (let's say, we support the last 2 releases).
2. We have 40+ git repos that forms a single installer. Some of those 40+ git repos create npm package or nuget package, and some others consume them (and make its own nuget/npm package sometimes.)
3. Every release gets their own branch and CI pipeline, so that updating a package in release-1.1 pipeline will not accidentally leak to any consumer of the package in release-1.0. This happens on all these 40+ git repos.
4. New release branch/CI pipeline is spawned about twice a year.

I see Artifactory provides multiple repos feature. In their recommended repo best practice doc, https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/, it suggests you use a separator for maturity, such as dev vs. prod.

To apply this to our situation, one idea is to perceive each release as maturity, so we will have dev, release-1.0, release-1.1, etc. artifactory repos, and each artifactory release repos are tied to their own branch. This will work okay but it takes more automation on artifactory side. I can see making separate Artifactory repos to manage permission, but making new repos just to filter packages feels overkill for us. There is no permission difference between releases.

Alternatively, we could go with single artifactory repo, and each package to be labeled with releases. Say, CI pipeline for release 1.0 will release a package with a label release-1.0. With a tooling like GitVersion that guarantees each CI pipeline will produce unique version number, this can provide nice filtering/grouping mechanism for all the packages without the burden of per-release repos. *Only if* nuget update or npm update can do the update of the package versions with label-based filtering.

jfrog cli provides a way to download files based upon labeling from certain artifactory repo. To build one git repo package, I could download all the packages from 40+ git repos with the label filtering, and then do nuget update using local folder. It doesn't sound ideal.

**I am surprised that nuget or npm already don't have *update with label filtering* feature. They support labels, but it is only for searching.** The only way I can think of is to write custom script that will go through each package reference in nuget.config or package.config (for npm), run query with jfrog cli (or api) to get the latest version of the package, and then update one by one. It will work, but I am wondering if this is the right solution since it involves handful of custom work.

Any advice from package management guru is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolvable by utilizing path, as noted in this article with baseRev.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts

It was important to recognize our releases are not maturity (as in dev vs. prod), but long-living branch. The difference is that long living branch's artifacts are compiled again, whereas prod artifacts are promoted from dev artifacts as-is. So when I tried to resolve long-living branch problem by applying maturity practice, it created awkward flow here and there.

Each long-living branch set of 40+ repos will provide/consume their own nuget packages within. To address this without making new repos for each release, we can utilize path in local repo, such as `artifactory.my-server.com/api/nuget/nuget-local/master/*` vs `artifactory.my-server.com/api/nuget/nuget-local/release-1/*`.

Unfortunately, [you can use path for push, but not for install.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191330/artifactorys-nuget-repo-with-a-path-it-works-for-push-but-not-for-install)
So for consumption side, you need to make one virtual repo for each release, which is not too big of a deal for us.