# Artifactory's nuget repo with a path: it works for push but not for install

Tags: nuget, artifactory

My %userprofile%\appdata\Roaming\nuget\NuGet.Config contains:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="rt1" value="https://my-server.com/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local" />
    <add key="rt2" value="https://my-server.com/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local/rt2" />
  </packageSources>
```

Now push works for both, but install works only with rt1.

```
nuget push My.Package.1.0.0.nupkg -source rt1  # works
nuget push My.Package.1.0.0.nupkg -source rt2  # works
nuget install My.Package                       # DOES NOT WORK IF I HAVE rt2 as source

OK https://my-server.com/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local/FindPackagesById()?id='My.Package'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 154ms

An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'My.Package' from source 'rt2'.
  Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://my-server.com/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local/rt2/FindPackagesById()?id='My.Package'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
  Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
```

Is this expected behavior? It looks like nuget expects FindPackagesById() to be available on repo url for install operation, and it is failing on rt2.

Is there any way to use the path as a source, without creating virtual repo with Includes/Excludes config? Would `jfrog nuget` cli give me different behavior?

I found it was also asked in jfrog: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-23310, but it was marked as Not a Bug without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Someone filed an issue with Artifactory/JFrog and they closed it as "Not a Bug": https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-23310

So apparently using package paths is not supported when pulling from Artifactory as a nuget source (even though it is supported when pushing).